# what is the difference between installing raid form bios and from disk utility in installing system?

Tags: installation, raid, disk, bios, mdadm

what is the difference in configuring raid in Idrak bios and configuring raid in installing Ubuntu or any other system??

is it faster in configuring raid from bios and more good performance and can i configure specific Part-ions to be raid 0 or 1 from bios as i can do it in the installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a very expensive hardware raid card, the raid functions offered by the bios are known as fakeraid because they are really software raid pretending to be hardware.  It is in fact, a bog standard AHCI sata controller with special software built into the bios and a special driver for Windows to perform raid in software.  As such, there is no performance advantage over pure software raid, which is what you get when you set it up with the Ubuntu installer or disk utility.  The only reason to use the fake raid is if you must dual boot with Windows, since Windows will not recognize Linux software raid.  Otherwise, it is not as well supported as plain software raid, and so should be avoided.